# Can't use or in if statement

Tags: php

Im with a little issue here, if I use 'or' everything returns false, heres my code:

```
if($_SESSION["login"] != 'joaomonteiro' or 'm1n6u3x' or 'jorgesaado17'){
    echo 'Acesso negado, redirecionando...';
    $main = "index.php";
    header('Location: '.$main);
}else{
    echo "success";
}
```

if I just use != 'name' it works fine, whoever with 'or' it doesn't

Comment: don't down vote, this is a legitimate question. this can be really confusing for some people at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work, because that's not how logical expressions work.

You have to compare every string by itself with `$_SESSION["login"]`:

```
if($_SESSION["login"] != 'joaomonteiro' 
    and $_SESSION["login"] != 'm1n6u3x' 
    and $_SESSION["login"] != 'jorgesaado17' ){
```

**Edit:** If the `or` operator should be used instead of `and`, only a little change is necessary:

```
if(!($_SESSION["login"] == 'joaomonteiro' 
    or $_SESSION["login"] == 'm1n6u3x' 
    or $_SESSION["login"] == 'jorgesaado17' ){
```

Comment: but doesn't and require the whole thing to be true?

Comment: Yes, for the condition to evaluate to true, every one of the three sub conditions has to be true. That is the case if `$_SESSION["login"]` is *not `joaomonteiro`* and *not `m1n6u3x`* and also *not `jorgesaado17`*. This is what you want to achieve, right?

Comment: Doesn't OP want "or"?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Using `and` or `or` just depends on how you formulate the condition, both can be used. What I believe he wants to achieve is to ensure that the name in `$_SESSION["login"]` is unequal to the three string literals.

Comment: Right you are. Forgot my DeMorgan's.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare each logical comparison with the string.

```
if($_SESSION["login"] != 'joaomonteiro' && $_SESSION["login"] != 'm1n6u3x' && $_SESSION["login"] != 'jorgesaado17') {
  // code
}
```

Comment: This condition does not make any sense whatsoever, though. It will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: oops i was typing entirely too fast &&

Answer (score 0):

That's because your are basically saying :

```php
if($_SESSION['login'] != 'joaomonteiro' or true or true) {

}
```

If you do this

```php
var_dump((boolean)"m1n6u3x");
var_dump((boolean)"jorgesaado17");
```

Both of them will return true.

I recommend you to read the documentation on booleans

[Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)